# Fuseki 4.4 UI - set endpoint for update queries

Tags: jena, fuseki

With Apache Jena Fuseki 4.3.2 it was possible to set/edit the endpoint on the UI to use update queries.

Fuseki 4.4 sets the query endpoint, which cannot be changed resulting in an error message on update queries. How can I set the update endpoint (replacing "query" with "update" does not do the trick)?

What do I miss?

(Simple configuration: downloaded Fuseki and started it with fuseki-server.bat)

Comment: If by "change query to update" you mean in "http://localhost:1234/#/dataset/ds/query" then that isn't the server endpoint for update. Go to the "info" page for the dataset and see the endpoints.

Comment: Yes, the info page shows the update endpoint as ``/ds/update``, but how can I make an update query from the UI?

Comment: Updates and In 4.4.0 the update isn't in the UI. IUt may be added back. You can add data or edit the data in other tabs. Updates can be sent from the command line. Or use 4.3.2.

Comment: @AndyS thank you for the clarification that this does not work. It would be nice to have this functionality back in the UI.

Comment: Mea culpa, it'll be back in 4.5.0. Sorry!

Comment: PR number 1200 fixes it :-) https://github.com/apache/jena/pull/1200/files